# how to run docker apache along with local system apache?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, apache2

i am working with multiple projects. after setup a project with docker. i lose my all local projects under `/var/www/html/` (*project is there, but can't access from url*).

since docker use port 80 i could not use that port for apache. and same for mysql it use 3306 port.changing my system's apache or mysql port will rework on Vhost or Project configuration files.

Comment: Does your Docker container needs to use the port 80?

Comment: @PierreC. yes it needed

Comment: Well, either you change apache's port or you change Docker's port. You can't have both on the same port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   ports:
        - "80:80"
```

Change this line to

```
    ports:
        - "8080:80"
```

Comment: could not change docker compose file. it is part of git repository. need to avoid `docker-compose.yml` in ` git add .` command. and while pull need to stash that file. will need to check those steps every time i do pull or push

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to change docker compose file (to export another port) then try to build and run docker commands manually.

go to your docker file and run below commands. this will export port 8080.

```
docker build -t <image_name>.
docker run -p 8080:80 --name <container_name> -d <image_name>
```